# How to measure total memory usage by some R code with parallel computing on Mac OS?

Tags: python, r, macos, memory

Basically I want to measure the total memory used by following R code on Mac OS. I know there is a [handy python app](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/Syrupy) `syrupy` that can take snapshots of the memory and CPU load of one or more running processes.

```
require(glmnet)    
require(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=4)
x = matrix(rnorm(1e5 * 100), 1e5, 100)
y = rnorm(1e5)
system.time(cvfit = cv.glmnet(x,y,parallel=TRUE))
```

Suppose I put above code in an R file named `test_memo.R`. I can use following command to measure the memory:

```
syrupy.py Rscript test_memo.R
```

This works fine if for serial computing. However, for parallel computing it appears to me that this app can only capture the memory used by just one process/thread/core, not not the total.

Could anyone tell me how to measure the total memory for the parallel-computing mode? Any solutions other than `syrupy` are highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.